# Calling a PL/SQL function that returns a {Table}%ROWTYPE from C#

Tags: c#, plsql, odp.net

I am using the Oracle Data Provider. I am having trouble calling a function that returns a record type defined as TABLE_NAME%ROWTYPE. How do you do this from C#

Answer (score 2):

ODP.net does not work with the record type. You could return a refcursor to your record and then access it from there.